# Firefox doesn't restore previous session when I have it checked in settings

Tags: firefox

For some reason Firefox doesn't restore my previous session, even though I have it checked in settings. It does however open the tabs, and most of them are just blank New Tabs, while the rest is the correct tabs.

Anyone know what can be the issue here? Im running the newest Ubuntu version:
**Description:  Ubuntu 20.04.3 LTS
Release:    20.04**

Its also the newest Firefox version